# get jenkins job xml configuration

Tags: python, jenkins

How to get jenkins job xml configuration without using the username and password ?

```
server=jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url,*username="",password=""*)
job_name = 'Test Job'

job_xml = server.get_job_config(job_name)
```

using the username and password details , xml is getting fetch but when not using the credentials, the job is throwing the error.

```
Authentication required

     <!-- You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't):
hudson.model.Hudson.Read
... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
    </body> </html>
```

Comment: You'd have to give Anonymous `hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead` in your authorization matrix, but that's generally not really a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Lan W, but that configuration needs to be done in the Jenkins Env,

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Application Security resides within the application. You can't expect to get access to the configuration unless authorized.